# Mock Unit Testing Add User Identity in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, moq

I am trying to write a unit test for my existing MVC Web Application. In that I am facing some problem like User Identity and Services calling.

My Base Controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
     public AppUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return new AppUser(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        }         
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class NewsController : BaseController
{
    private readonly iNewsService _newsService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public NewsController(iNewsService newsService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _newsService = newsService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public ActionResult List(int CompanyID == 0)
    {
        var data = _newsService.List(CompanyID, CurrentUser.CompanyType);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Testing Code:

```
[TestClass]
public class NewsControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void NewsList()
    {
        var mockNewsService = new Mock<iNewsService>();
        var mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();

        IList<Claim> claimCollection = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("UserName", "admin"),
            new Claim("CompanyType", "true"),
        };

        var identityMock = new Mock<ClaimsIdentity>();
        identityMock.Setup(x => x.Claims).Returns(claimCollection);

        var cp = new Mock<ClaimsPrincipal>();
        cp.Setup(m => m.HasClaim(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
        cp.Setup(m => m.Identity).Returns(identityMock.Object);


        var contextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        contextMock.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(cp.Object);

        var controllerContextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();            
        controllerContextMock.Setup(con => con.HttpContext).Returns(contextMock.Object);
        controllerContextMock.Setup(con => con.HttpContext.User).Returns(cp.Object);

        NewsController controller = new NewsController(mockNewsService.Object, mockMapper.Object);
        controller.ControllerContext = controllerContextMock.Object;

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.List(1) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);

    }
 }
```

AppUser Class:

```
public class AppUser : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public AppUser(ClaimsPrincipal principal) : base(principal)
    {
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FindFirst("UserName").Value;
        }
    }

    public string CompanyType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FindFirst("CompanyType").Value;
        }
    }
}
```

INewsServices :

```
public interface iNewsService
{
    IEnumerable<Model.News> List(string companyType, string CompanyID);
}
```

**Note : INewsServices is separate library**

This is my actual code but its not working always my `CurrentUser` is null value. I am not able to assign the value in `CurrentUser` in parent Controller and some time my news services is also not calling the List method.

Comment: See the base controller there i have declared CurrentUser. While running the above Code CurrentUser is showing as null value ('CurrentUser.CompanyType' threw an exception type as 'System.NullReferanceException')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you mock the `ClaimsPrincipal`s is causing the `FindFirst` to return `null` and when you call `Value` on that it gets NRE. No need to mock the claims principals just create new instances for the test.

```
[TestClass]
public class NewsControllerTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void _NewsList() {
        //Arrange           
        var companyId = 1;
        var companyType = "someType";
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("UserName", "admin"),
            new Claim("CompanyType", companyType),
        };
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));

        var contextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        contextMock.Setup(_ => _.User).Returns(principal);

        var fakeNews = new List<News>() { new News(), new News() };
        var mockNewsService = new Mock<INewsService>();
        mockNewsService
            .Setup(_ => _.List(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
            .Returns(fakeNews);

        var controller = new NewsController(mockNewsService.Object, Mock.Of<IMapper>());
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(contextMock.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.List(companyId) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        mockNewsService.Verify(_ => _.List(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
    }
}
```

You should also consider updating `AppUser` to avoid the NRE

```
public class AppUser : ClaimsPrincipal {
    public AppUser(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        : base(principal) {
    }

    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.FindFirst("UserName")?.Value;
        }
    }

    public string CompanyType {
        get {
            return this.FindFirst("CompanyType")?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```